# C++: How to get vector to print user input?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to print out my vector's user input. I think there's something wrong specifically with my iterator loop, but I'm not sure what. I've been toying around with this and I'm stumped. I'm also having trouble with my sentinel value - my program ceases to continue after entering in my sentinel value. Am I missing something?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code: (there are some variables here that you might notice that aren't being used in this sample of code. i'm using those variables for another portion of my program).

Any help that you could provide in regards to this would be INCREDIBLY helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `checkCounter > 0` use `check_amounts.size() > 0` to see if the vector contains any data at all. You don't really need `checkCounter` in your code - `check_amounts.size()` could do.

Comment: You need to treat your code as an experiment platform.  Something's not working, so it's time to find out _experimentally_ where it first goes wrong.  Add code to print important values at strategic locations.  Move that code around.  See where things go wrong.  Question everything.  This is a fundamental form of debugging (out of many other forms) that will help you critically assess code throughout your journey as a programmer.

Comment: Thank you StillLearning - I modified my code and now I have actual output! I am getting a strange output, but I'm going to try to figure out how to get it to print properly. Paddy, I definitely understand what you mean. I have been rearranging things for a few hours now and needed a fresh set of eyes to help me see my code in a different way. Getting feedback from others allows me to critically look at what I'm doing from another perspective or in a way that I would not have originally done. I am still practicing C++ and hope to get better at assessing code over time :)

Comment: Look up rubber duck debugging.  Step through your program in your debugger, and see if it is doing what you expect.  Hint:  You never use val1 etc.  Hint2:  You should declare them as `const char* const val1...;` (the first const means you can't alter the strings, the second means you cant change the pointers.)

Comment: Seems like OP deleted all the code from the question...

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your check_amounts vector a second time, right before your output loop, so you're outputting the contents of an empty vector.  Delete the second declaration.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that earlier. Thank you. I've removed the second declaration, but the overall output is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your code got caught in infinite loop at :

for (i = 0; amount < length; i++) length /= 10;

Because amount = -1, length = 0.
Also do not use != for double values, e.g. (amount != -1). Use < or > . Equality check is not reliable due to inexact bit-pattern

Answer (score 0):

this is what i get when i run your code:

```
This program inputs a dollar amount and prints it in check-format.
Input up to five check amounts, one at a time. (Enter -1 to quit)
5
Input up to five check amounts, one at a time. (Enter -1 to quit)
10
Input up to five check amounts, one at a time. (Enter -1 to quit)
15
Input up to five check amounts, one at a time. (Enter -1 to quit)
20
Input up to five check amounts, one at a time. (Enter -1 to quit)
25

The check-formated dollar amount for your check(s) are printed as follows: 5 **** 25.00
10 **** 25.00
15 **** 25.00
20 **** 25.00
25 **** 25.00
```

Can't see a problem with printing out vector's user input. Avik Paul is right for the sentinel case by the way. You should be using the last valid amount maybe.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to fix my output so that the formatting is correct. The only thing is that when I type -1 to end, the rest of my program fails to execute.

Comment: @Clark - If you have not figured it out already... see the answer from Avik Paul. It explains the reason, i.e. endless loop.